# Stream body bytes from Surf request to file

Tags: rust

I'm making requests for files using [surf](https://github.com/http-rs/surf) and I want to save the request body in a file. But these files are too large to store in memory so I need to be able to stream it to the file.

Surf looks like [it supports this](https://docs.rs/surf/1.0.1/surf/struct.Request.html#examples-11) but I have not found a way to save the result in a file.

My attempt looks like this

```
let mut result = surf::get(&link)
  .await
  .map_err(|err| anyhow!(err))
  .context(format!("Failed to fetch from {}", &link))?;
let body = surf::http::Body::from_reader(req, None);
let mut image_tempfile: File = tempfile::tempfile()?;
image_tempfile.write(body);
```

but this does not work as `write()` expects a `&[u8]` which I believe would require reading the whole body in to memory. Is there any way I can write the content of the surf `Body` to a file without holding it all in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surf's [`Response`](https://docs.rs/surf/latest/surf/struct.Response.html) implements `AsyncRead` (a.k.a. [`async_std::io::Read`](https://docs.rs/async-std/latest/async_std/io/trait.Read.html)) and if you convert your temporary file into something that implements `AsyncWrite` (like [`async_std::fs::File`](https://docs.rs/async-std/latest/async_std/fs/struct.File.html)) then you can use [`async_std::io::copy`](https://docs.rs/async-std/latest/async_std/io/fn.copy.html) to move bytes from one to the other asynchronously, without buffering the whole file:

```
let mut response = surf::get("https://www.google.com").await.unwrap();
let mut tempfile = async_std::fs::File::from(tempfile::tempfile().unwrap());

async_std::io::copy(&mut response, &mut tempfile).await.unwrap();
```

Comment: This seems to work. Do you know if its possible to convert back to an `std::fs::File` after? Or alternatively to `tokio::fs::File`?

Comment: That I do not know, and a quick look seems it's not possible, but I'm not too familiar with async-std.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be what I'm seeing. Looking easier at this point to replace surf with reqwest and keep everything tokio compatible.